# cakephp jQuery multiple action for an event showing error

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, jquery-events, action

I am trying to implement a ajax with jQuery and some jQuery actions for a change event. My code:

```
$this->Js->get('#PermenantDistrict')->event('change',
$this->Js->alert('hello world !'),
$this->Js->request(array(
    'controller'=>'employee_personals',
    'action'=>'getEpfno'
    ), array(
    'update'=>'#success',
    'async' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
    'dataExpression'=>true,
    'data'=> $data,
    'before'   => '$("#loader").attr("style", " "),$("#success").attr("style", "display:none")', 
    'complete' => '$("#loader").attr("style", "display:none"),$("#success").attr("style", " ")',
    ))
);
```

But I am getting a warning:

> Warning (2): array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
> [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\JqueryEngineHelper.php, line 174].

I want to know how to implement multiple actions for a single event with jQuery helper in cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to send second argument as array.

Also I think it's a bad idea to use JsHelper because it's about to get deprecated (as far I know).

Let me suggest to not mix javascript with php because it could quickly become a mess.